# "When are you free except Tuesday?"

Tags: questions

I’d like to say “when are you free except Tuesday?”. Is it grammatically correct?

Comment: Hello Ayaka.  Questions like this, which ask "is it correct", yes or no are not so good.  You need to provide some context.  "Who are you talking to?"  "What are you talking about?"  "Why are you so worried about this sentence that you came here to ask about it."

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

It is pretty clear what you are asking. There are really two sentences here
"When are you free?" is the question, and "You can say any day except Tuesday." is a clarification to the question. You've then reduced the second sentence and merged it with the first.  It is the sort of thing that is common enough in casual speech, or even in emails.

To be grammatical you need to use "except Tuesday" to modify "day" and not "free".

So you could say "What day, except Tuesday, are you free?"

But what you really want to say is  "I'm free on any day except Tuesday. When are you free?"

Comment: @Ayaka, "Other than" works the same way as "except", and is more natural in North America for this context.